# How to auto format my textbox in license format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried searching on the internet for answer but the closest I can find is in [this jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nY2QT/1386/)

What I wanted to do is when the page loads, the textbox is automatically filled with this words `Furniture/Chair/Square`. In addition, the user can input some text next to the words like this `Furniture/Chair/Square/_ _ _/_ _ _`. The user cannot erase the automatically filled words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a work around with some reference from jwa's post and RegEx:

```js
$(function() {
  $('label.prefilled input[type="text"][placeholder]').on('input', function() {
    var fmt = this.placeholder.split('');
    var len = this.placeholder.match(/_/g).length;
    var val = this.value.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, '').split('').slice(0, len);
    var res = '',
      v, f;
    while ((v = val.shift()) && (f = fmt.shift())) {
      if ('_' === f) {
        res += v;
      } else {
        res += f + v;
        fmt.shift();
      }
    }
    res += fmt.join('');
    this.value = res;
  }).trigger('input');
});
```

```css
label.prefilled input[type="text"] {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

label.prefilled {
  border: 1px ridge gray;
}

div.card {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <label class='prefilled'>
  Furniture/Chair/Square/<input type="text" placeholder="___/___"/>
</label>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <label class='prefilled'>
  Electronic/Handheld/<input type="text" placeholder="______/______"/>
</label>
</div>
```

> How do I include numbers?

Use `[^a-z0-9]` in this line `this.value.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, '')`

```js
$(function() {
  $('label.prefilled input[type="text"][placeholder]').on('input', function() {
    var fmt = this.placeholder.split('');
    var len = this.placeholder.match(/_/g).length;
    var val = this.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, '').split('').slice(0, len);
    var res = '',
      v, f;
    while ((v = val.shift()) && (f = fmt.shift())) {
      if ('_' === f) {
        res += v;
      } else {
        res += f + v;
        fmt.shift();
      }
    }
    res += fmt.join('');
    this.value = res;
  }).trigger('input');
});
```

```css
label.prefilled input[type="text"] {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

label.prefilled {
  border: 1px ridge gray;
}

div.card {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <label class='prefilled'>
  Furniture/Chair/Square/<input type="text" placeholder="___/___"/>
</label>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <label class='prefilled'>
  Electronic/Handheld/<input type="text" placeholder="______/______"/>
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup, this is the exactly I wanted! I have to study this code. Thank you very much!

Comment: Btw, is there a way to not using label? I mean the text is already inside the textbox which user cannot erase it.

Comment: How do I include numbers?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by assigning a label to the input field you create. For example...

```css
#text-input {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
label{
    border:solid 1px black;
    padding-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<label for="text-input">
  furniture chair square
  <input type="text" id="text-input" />
</label>
```

Comment: how do I limit the user input to 3 words followed by `/` and then another 3 words?

Answer (score 0):

Use RegExp to solve your problem.

You may add some css or addition text to notice the user error input.

```js
function checkStr(str){
    //check pattern
    result = str.match(/^Furniture\/Chair\/Square([a-zA-Z\/]+)?/)
    if(result == null || result[0].length !== str.length){
      //revert the input field to default
      document.getElementById('userText').value = "Furniture/Chair/Square"
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Furniture/Chair/Square" id="userText" oninput="checkStr(value)"></input>
<p id='asd'></p>
```

Comment: i just pasted in jfiddle, not sure why the filled text can overwrites. Also, how to limit text after the filled text to 3 digits?

Comment: `document.getElementById('userText')` here you select the element with id "userText" which is the input box. Then you can change the value by element.value directly

Comment: you can add a condition to check the length of the whole text